# R: Stepwise regression with multiple orthogonal polynomials

Tags: r, regression, polynomials

I am currently looking for an "optimal" fit for some data. I would like to use AIC stepwise regression to find the "best" polynomial regression for my outcome (y) with three variables (a, b, c) and maximum ^3. I also have interactions.
If I use:

`lm_poly <- lm(y ~ a + I(a^2) + I(a^3) + b + I(b^2) + I(b^3) + c + a:b, my_data)
stepAIC(lm_poly, direction = "both")`

I will get collinearities due to the use of `I(i^j)`-terms. This shows in the beta regression coefficients of the final fit. There are terms >|1|.

**Is there a possibility to do stepwise regression with orthogonal terms?**

Using `poly()` would be nice, but I just don't understand how to do stepwise regression with `poly()`.

```
lm_poly2 <- lm(y ~ poly(a,3) + poly(b,3) + c + a:b, my_data) 
stepAIC(lm_poly2, direction = "both")
```

This will not include steps with `a`, `a^2`(and b respectivly) and thus not find the results I am looking for.

(I know, that I might still have collinearities do to the interaction `a:b`.)

I hope, someone can understand my point.

Thank you in advance.
Jans